How to delete the app icon on the desktop
I am new to Linux and Fedora 40 used now. I just deleted the navicat-sqlite-en-xxx.AppImage from Downloads folder successfully since I want to uninstall it.
But
Navicat 17 for Sqlite app icon still on my desktop. How could I delete it?

link   desktop showapp   and link desktop app icon

Assuming it's a .desktop file, all you need to do is delete it. If you need to check, open a terminal, run ls ~/Desktop, and look for it in the resulting list.
If the icon is in the collection displayed when clicking "Show Apps", you should find it's .desktop file in one of the following locations, in which case you'll need to delete it from there:

~/.local/share/applications
/usr/share/applications

or possibly

/usr/local/share/applications


Sources

How to Add Your App or Script to Start Menu (Show Apps) in Linux -   https://fostips.com/add-app-start-menu-ubuntu-linux/
Clean up Shortcut Icons after Removing Apps in Ubuntu, Fedora & other Linux - https://fostips.com/clean-up-shortcut-icons-linux/



Dear David, It return nothing when I run ls ~/Desktop.  And I don't have any App icon on desktop untill I click SHOW APP ,and then these APP icon showed out.
